# Jquery validations on dynamic php echo fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

Hi i am developing a multi page form in which you have to enter the number of people in the first step and then in the next step you enter the information for the same number of people.
Now i am posting the data to step 2 and fetching the data via sessions.i am using this code inside form body .

```
 <?php 
 $i=0; 
 for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['number'];$i++) 
   echo $message='
                <div class="section colm colm4">
                <label for="firstname" class="field prepend-icon">
               <input type="text" name="firstname['.$i.']" id="firstname" class="gui-input" placeholder="First Name">
                </div> 
                 ';
        ?>
```

and this is working fine.But the problem is when i am trying to validate the form using jquery its not validating.
EDIT : okay now i know that in validation each and every rule name should be unique.but how to do that ? As i do not know the number of fields

```
'firstname[1]': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
                },
 'firstname[2]': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
                },
 'firstname[3]': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
                },
```

this is a sample rule for three fields how can i set up a loop in there for 10 fields  ?

Comment: You are adding a validation to the element `'firstname[]'` which doesn't exists: you need to use it with an index or automate it somehow so that it applies to all of the fields you have created.

Comment: what validation library are u using? where and how u r adding this validation? and u dont have a element named `firstname[]` u have `firstname[someindex]`...

Comment: okay but then how to add the index as i do not know how many fields will be there?They can be from 1-10.
i am using .validate()

Comment: Correct answer by @Ryley posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [$.rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#rules(-%E2%80%9Cadd%E2%80%9D-rules-)) function of the jQuery Validation library.  It would be smart to add a class of `firstname` to each of your inputs, then you can do this:

```
$('.firstname').each(function(){
    $(this).rules('add',{
        required:true,
        //other rules as you wish
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There *may* be more than one reason, but the thing I see is that your ID's are not unique, you should set the `id` value the same as you have done so with the `name`.

Comment: okay i got it that the id and name  have to be unique in the rules too. but how i am supposed to add it to my rules